# serialise polymorphic json to specific jsonnode

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have list of abstract class

```
List<Messaging> data;
```

Messaging is an abstract class and 3 other classes are extending this class.

For example,

```
   Message class extends Messaging
   Product class extends Messaging
   Filter class extends Messaging
```

I am adding all messages in the above list

I have used @JsonTypeInfo on Messaging class like below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({  
    @Type(value = Message.class, name = "message"),  
    @Type(value = Filter.class, name = "filter"),
    @Type(value = Product.class , name = "product")})
```

When I serialise this Java object to JSON using jackson I am getting values like below:

```
   {
        "@type": "message",
        "type": "text",
        "value": "Is this the information you need"
    }
```

I want my value as below:

```
"message" : {
        "type": "text",
        "value": "Is this the information you need"
}
```

How to serialise list of polymorphic object to different node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `JsonTypeInfo` to include as `WRAPPER_OBJECT`.

e.g.:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
```